# Stripe subscription renewal - emailing the invoice instead of automatic charging

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

According to Stripe documentation concerning [Subscription renewal invoices](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/subscription#collect-payment) *"When an invoice is due, Stripe tries to collect payment by either automatically charging the payment method on file, o**r emailing the invoice to customer**s."*

But I cannot find in the Stripe API how to set up emailing of the invoice for subscription renewal instead of letting Stripe automatically charge existing customers. Automatic charging seems like a default option  that cannot be changed through the API as future payments are generated automatically.
My flow should be customer trendily:

- I had set up a product in Stripe 1 year subscription payment
- a customer pays for the first year using his/her card
- next year Stripe emails the customer with invoice and payment instruction to continue his yearly subscription without Stripe trying to charge him in advance automatically

I find it not too customer friendly to charge him/her automatically. Yearly subscription may be too long for the customer to remember his/her subscription or even worse he/she has provided payment data to Stripe to store and use. It is better to avoid any unexpected customer surprise.

Thank you very much.

Edit:
I have already tried this without any success.

```js
     const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(
      {
        customer: stripe_customer, 
        mode: "subscription",
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items: [{
          price: priceId,
          quantity: 1
        }], 
        automatic_tax: {
          enabled: true,
        },
        collection_method: "send_invoice", // or data: [{ collection_method: "send_invoice"}],
        customer_update: {
          address: 'auto',
        },
        success_url: "http://localhost:5173/payment/success",
        cancel_url: "http://localhost:5173/payment/canceled",
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Subscription that automatically emails Invoices to customers by setting `collection_method: send_invoice` (see https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-collection_method). You may also find it helpful to read some of their invoice-specific documentation that covers this: https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/integration

Edit - You left out the detail you were using Checkout Sessions initially, which changes things. There is no way to directly create a Subscription through Checkout that has `collection_method: send_invoice`. If you using Checkout is a hard requirement then you need to do the following:

- Create the Checkout Session
- Provide payment in the Checkout UI. Once payment is complete this will create a Subscription with `collection_method: charge_automatically`
- After it's been created, update the Subscription to set `collection_method: send_invoice` so that all future renewals email the invoice to the customer.

Comment: I have already tried it but it does not work.

Comment: Thank you very much. Figured it out as well, only two step process is possible by updating collection_method after first payment is done.